# arrange the vector by showing the even values ​first and then the odd ones

Tags: c, vector

Insert in a vector B, from its beginning, the even numbers of vector A and, from its end, the
odd numbers of vector A (this item must be solved with only a single structure of
repetition);

i don't know the conditions i have tu put in do while loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, A[25], B[25], testeNumeroIgual = 0, aux;
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    i = 0;
    
   do {
        A[i] = rand() % 40;
        testeNumeroIgual = 0;
        
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (A[j] == A[i]) {
                testeNumeroIgual = 1;
            }
        }
        
        if (testeNumeroIgual == 0)
            i++;
   } while(i < 25);
   

   i = 0;
   
   do {
        if (A[i] % 2 == 0) {
            B[i] = A[i];    
        }
        else {
            B[25 - i] = A[i];
        }   
        
        i++;
   } while(i < 25); 
   
   for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", B[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tip: Keep two indexes, for head (0) and tail (24), if it's odd insert where head points and move the head. If it's even, insert where tail is and move the tail. Also 25 - i when i = 0 is undefined behavior since indexes start at 0, so your last index is 24.

Answer (score 0):

Generate the random number into a specific loop to isolate the algorithm.

Then use two indexes tail and head to put it on the right place.
Increase head and decrease tail when you insert.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 25

int main()
{
    int i, A[SIZE], B[SIZE], tail, head ;
    srand(time(NULL));

    /* generate random number for A */
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        A[i] = rand() % 40;
    }

    tail = SIZE - 1;
    head = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (A[i] % 2) {
            B[tail--] = A[i];
        } else {
            B[head++] = A[i];
        }
    }
    printf("A: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d %d\n",i, A[i]);
    }
    printf("\nB: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%i %d\n", i, B[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```